# Is there a way to extract JSON property labels from a JSON schema using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, schema

What I want to do is have Gson Type Adapters that don't have to have the property labels for a given JSON object hard coded into the adapter, but instead pull the Strings from the JSON Schema.

So if I have a schema like this (borrowing from json-schema.org):

```json
{
  "$id": "/schemas/address",

  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": { "type": "string" },
    "city": { "type": "string" },
    "state": { "type": "string" }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to extract the property names "street_address", "city", and "state" from the schema and assign them to variables in a Gson TypeAdapter or Factory such that I don't have to declare a String like

```java
String streetName = "street_address";
```

But could instead do something in the vein of

```java
String streetName = getSchemaProperty("/schemas/address").getProperty(0);
```

Where getSchemaProperty() would get the object schema from the "/schemas/address" file and getProperty would return the first property label in the schema.  That way, if the schema was updated with new property labels, I would not have to update the Adapters with new Strings.

I can certainly write something that would do this (parse the schema file(s) and extract that information), I'm just wondering if that kind of work has already been done (maybe with annotations or some such?) & I'm just missing it?

Answer (score 0):

Easier than I thought, actually, since a Schema is a JSON file.
Here is an example Schema:

```
{
    "$id": "/path/to/schema/MySchema",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#",
    "title": "My Example JSON Schema",
    "description": "JSON Schema for me",
    "$comment": "Hey!  A Comment!",     
    "$defs" :
    {
        "My Class":
        {
            "$comment": "Another Comment!  I love comments, so useful!",
            "type": "object",
            "required": [ "Value", "Description" ],
            "properties":
            {
                "Value": { "type": "number" },
                "Description": { "type": "string"   }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the default constructor of my Google GSON Type Adapter:

```
public MyTypeAdapter()
{
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/schema/MySchema.json");
    InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
    JsonObject schemaJO= JsonParser.parseReader(isr).getAsJsonObject;
    JsonObject thisJO = schemaJO.getAsJsonObject("$defs").getAsJsonObject("My Class").getAsJsonObject("properties");
    //Get the list of property labels\names\keys
    Set<String> keySet = thisJO .keySet();
    //loop over the set and distribute the Strings as desired.
}
```

Easy Peasy Lemon Squeezy!